# ROR inner join gives duplicate value

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, search, ruby-on-rails-4, inner-join

Hello I get duplicate rows of data by inner join.and i write inner join with OR condition.

**Controller** *userscontroller.rb*

```
@users = User.search(params[:search])
@users = User.joins([:requests]).where("name LIKE ? OR destination LIKE ?","#{params[:search]}%", "#{params[:search]}%")
```

**View** *searches/index.html.haml*

```
%aside.span6
  = form_tag(:users, method: "get") do
    = text_field_tag "search", params[:search], placeholder: "Enter Name"
    %br/
    = submit_tag "Search", name: nil, class: "btn-custom-darken"
    %br/
    %br/
- @users.each do |user|
 = render user
= will_paginate @users
```

**View** *users/index.html.haml*

```
%div{align: "center"}
%b List of Users
- if current_user != (@user)
%ol.microposts
- @users.each do |user|
= render user
```

The problem is duplicate data printed as a output after search. If user posted 3 request then user will be printed as output 3 times. So image of user is printed 3 times with duplicate request data. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us your sample output.

Comment: [Sample output image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/i2BD2.png) @Pavan

Comment: Which one of those is a duplicate data?

Comment: Ajay5.read last line of my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get unique values from a join just add the `.uniq` function to the call. And also when reusing one single input for multiple queries you can use the ruby key:value pair syntax.

```
@users = User.joins([:requests])
             .where("name LIKE :search OR 
                     destination LIKE :search",
                     {search: params[:search]})
             .uniq
```